# How to manually set partition key for AWS Amplify DynamoDB API

Tags: react-native, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Beginner to AWS trying to use AWS Amplify as a backend for a react native application. I've created an API with a schema using the Amplify wizard. I specified an id field that has value type of ID which becomes the partition key. I would like to set this key myself because when a user creates their profile, I want to store it and be able to fetch it with an id. However, it looks like the query doesn't even expect an id field because the dynamodb automatically assigns an id/partition key upon creation. I don't know how to get this id and I want to if possible specify my own partition key. I tried adding id in the input type of creation but the entries that are getting created in dynamodb still doesn't use the id I pass in.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out more about resolvers, you can specify your own id if you configure your resolver corresponding to the mutation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).